# I dont seem to find App Transport Security so that I may disable it temporarily

Tags: ios, node.js, http, server, info.plist

I am new to iOS app development. I need to disable the App Transport security so that I may test my app with node.js. But when I go to info.plist, I dont seem to find the option at all. Below I am attaching the screenshot of the info.plist tab. (Kindly note that I am using Xcode Version 11.4.1 (11E503a)). Thanks a lot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swkat.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not present by default. You need the add it into your info.plist. Click the `plus` button and start typing `App Transport Security Settings` it'll auto-complete for you. In that, you can find the option `Allow Arbitrary Loads` set it to `YES` or `NO` according to your requirement.

You can also do this by right-clicking the info.plist file and selecting `Open as source code` and pasting the following into that after the first `<dict>`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```